# Riddle Number Two

Tags: riddle

This next riddle will be a bit more challenging.

> I am two halves of a whole,
>
> For now only some remain.
>
> What am I?

Comment: Any hints, please?

Answer (score 8):

> It could be the letter 'V'. W contains two V's. If we take the **W** out of **W**hole we get 'hole' which looks like letter **O**. That's what remains for the word n**O**w

Comment: That's incorrect, but I will admit that is good reasoning.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the word in english, but are you:

> Time of a day

You are two halves of a whole:

> You have 12hours AM and PM to make a day

For now only some remain

> You only have some hours remain to complete a day (go to next day)

Comment: Wrong answer, but keep trying.

Answer (score 1):

Let's get literal:

> You are a fraction, or more specifically, **1/2**
>  two halves (1/2) make a whole (1), and 1/2 could also be written as a remainder (r) or with remainder notation.

---

Original attempt:

> **something** or **somebody**.
>  1. *some* and *thing*/*body* are two words that when together make another whole word.
>  2. something and somebody refer to a whole thing/person.
>  3. 'For now, only "some" remain(s)'. Specifically half the word remains until the puzzle is solved and the whole word is known.
>  4. What am I: you are either *something* or *somebody* (like say @Edward Nigma)

Comment: Wrong, but keep trying.

Answer (score 1):

Are you:

> The UK's relationship with the EU aka Brexit?

*I am two halves of a whole*

> Roughly half of the whole country voted for Brexit (52%) and roughly half against (48%).

*For now only some remain*

> The vote was to either leave the EU or remain in the EU. The two sides then became dubbed Leavers and Remainers.

Comment: Not even close, but keep trying.

Answer (score 1):

Are you your own nemesis

> BATMAN?

You are Edward Nigma, the

> given name of the villain [The Riddler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riddler), whose name is hinted to in the title. [Batman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman) is of course a whole comprising the halves bat and man. His name includes the string "atm", which is a *partial* - i.e. abbreviated - way to express "now" - that is, "**a**t **t**he **m**oment", for . . .

For now only some remain.

Comment: I love how you deduced my identity.

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> Puzzle pieces

I am two halves of a whole,

> two pieces will fit together to form 1 new bigger piece to the puzzle

For now only some remain.

> if you put 2 puzzle pieces together you can go on with the ones left to complete the puzzle

Comment: Negative! Keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> The Northern White Rhino?

Because:

> The last male died this year, leaving only two females left.

Comment: I love this answer, but it's incorrect!

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> **Marriage**. Two people starts life together to become One whole family, For now only some (Love, kids etc..) remain

Comment: No, but good analysis of the riddle.